# Lookup method resolution failed, nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException. Failed to interospect class from classLoader

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is the error below

cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerOnboardingEndpoint' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/fi/op/bcsio/endpoint/CustomerOnboardingEndpoint.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controller' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/fi/op/bcsio/controller/Controller.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceFacadeImpl': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [fi.op.bcsio.service.impl.ServiceFacadeImpl] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@5e853265]"}}

```
Here is my controller class
package fi.op.bcsio.controller;

import static fi.op.jopo.logging.LogMarker.SENSITIVE_DATA;
import static fi.op.jopo.logging.LogMarker.TECH;
import static org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import fi.op.bcsio.bancs.business.CreateCustomerBancsRequestBody;
import fi.op.bcsio.bancs.business.CreateCustomerShipBancsRequestBody;
import fi.op.bcsio.bancs.response.bean.SuccessResponse;
import fi.op.bcsio.configurableproperties.ExternalProperty;
import fi.op.bcsio.domain.bean.bancs.customership.request.CreateCustomerShipRequest;
import fi.op.bcsio.domain.bean.bancs.request.CustomerCustomerShipRequest;
import fi.op.bcsio.domain.bean.bancs.response.CustomerNCustomershipCheck;
import fi.op.bcsio.domain.bean.luukku.response.LuukkuBasicInfoResponse;
import fi.op.bcsio.domain.bean.luukku.response.LuukkuCustomerShipResponse;
import fi.op.bcsio.errorhandler.DateUtility;
import fi.op.bcsio.exception.BadRequestError;
import fi.op.bcsio.exception.InternalServerError;
import fi.op.bcsio.exception.UnauthorizedError;
import fi.op.bcsio.jwt.TokenValidation;
import fi.op.bcsio.luukku.business.LuukkuLogic;
import fi.op.bcsio.service.ServiceFacade;
import fi.op.bcsio.validation.bean.RequestBodyValidation;
import fi.op.jopo.security.ecb.EcbUtils;

@Component
public class Controller {

    private final Logger logger = getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    ServiceFacade serviceFacade;

    @Autowired
    TokenValidation tokenValidation;

    @Autowired
    LuukkuLogic luukkuLogic;

    @Autowired
    CreateCustomerBancsRequestBody createCustomerBancsRequestBody;

    @Autowired
    ExternalProperty externalProperty;

    @Autowired
    EcbUtils ecbUtils;

    @Autowired
    CreateCustomerShipBancsRequestBody createCustomerShipBancsRequestBody;
    
    
    String internalServerExceptionMessage = "Unable to process the request!";
    

    public void validatingToken(String authorizationToken, String requestId,
            RequestBodyValidation requestBodyValidation) {
        tokenValidation.validateToken(authorizationToken, requestId, requestBodyValidation);
    }

    public ResponseEntity<?> checkAndOnboardCustomer(RequestBodyValidation requestBodyValidation, String requestId,
            String authorizationToken) {

        try {
            CustomerNCustomershipCheck enquiryServiceResponse = serviceFacade.customerandCustomershipCheck(
                    requestBodyValidation.getBankNumber(), requestBodyValidation.getCustomerId(), "18", requestId);
            logger.info(SENSITIVE_DATA,"Response from BaNCS Customer and CustomerShip enquiry Service {}", enquiryServiceResponse);

            if ((enquiryServiceResponse.getCustomership().getCustomershipExists().equals(1))
                    && (enquiryServiceResponse.getCustomership().getCustomerExists().equals(1))) {

                SuccessResponse successResponse = new SuccessResponse("CUSTOMER EXISTS", DateUtility.getDate(),
                        requestId);
             logger.info(TECH,"CUSTOMER EXISTS");
                return new ResponseEntity<SuccessResponse>(successResponse, HttpStatus.OK);

            } else if ((enquiryServiceResponse.getCustomership().getCustomershipExists().equals(0))
                    && (enquiryServiceResponse.getCustomership().getCustomerExists().equals(0))) {

                String encryptedssn = ecbUtils.encrypt(requestBodyValidation.getCustomerId(), "");

                LuukkuBasicInfoResponse luukkuBasicInfoResponse = serviceFacade.luukkuBasicInfoResponse(requestId,
                        authorizationToken);

                logger.info(SENSITIVE_DATA,"Response received from Luukku basic info is {}", luukkuBasicInfoResponse);
                LuukkuCustomerShipResponse[] luukkuCustomerShipResponse = serviceFacade.luukkuCustomerShipResponse(requestId,
                        authorizationToken, encryptedssn);

                logger.info(SENSITIVE_DATA,"Response receives from Luukku customership is {}", (Object) luukkuCustomerShipResponse);

                CustomerCustomerShipRequest customerCustomerShipRequest = createCustomerBancsRequestBody
                        .bancsCreateCustomerRequest(requestId, externalProperty, requestBodyValidation,
                                luukkuBasicInfoResponse, luukkuCustomerShipResponse);

                logger.info(SENSITIVE_DATA,"Create Customer request body sent to Bancs is {}", customerCustomerShipRequest);
                serviceFacade.createCustomerCustomership(requestId, customerCustomerShipRequest);

                SuccessResponse successResponse = new SuccessResponse("CUSTOMER ONBOARDED", DateUtility.getDate(),
                        requestId);
                 logger.info(TECH,"CUSTOMER ONBOARDED");     
                return new ResponseEntity<SuccessResponse>(successResponse, HttpStatus.CREATED);

            } else if ((enquiryServiceResponse.getCustomership().getCustomershipExists().equals(0))
                    && (enquiryServiceResponse.getCustomership().getCustomerExists().equals(1))) {
                String encryptedssn = ecbUtils.encrypt(requestBodyValidation.getCustomerId(), "");
                LuukkuCustomerShipResponse[] luukkuCustomerShipResponse = serviceFacade.luukkuCustomerShipResponse(requestId,
                        authorizationToken, encryptedssn);
                logger.info(SENSITIVE_DATA,"Response received from Luukku customership is {}", (Object) luukkuCustomerShipResponse);

                CreateCustomerShipRequest createCustomerShipRequestBody = createCustomerShipBancsRequestBody
                        .createCustomerShipBancsRequestBody(externalProperty, requestBodyValidation,
                                luukkuCustomerShipResponse);
                logger.info(SENSITIVE_DATA,"Customership request body {}", createCustomerShipRequestBody);
                serviceFacade.createCustomerShip(requestId, createCustomerShipRequestBody);
                
                SuccessResponse successResponse = new SuccessResponse("CUSTOMERSHIP ONBOARDED", DateUtility.getDate(),
                        requestId);
                logger.info(TECH,"CUSTOMERSHIP ONBOARDED");
                return new ResponseEntity<SuccessResponse>(successResponse, HttpStatus.CREATED);
            } else {
                logger.info(TECH,"Customer and CustomerShip exist is neither of case 0 0 , 1 0, 1 1");
                throw new InternalServerError(internalServerExceptionMessage, requestId);

            }
        } catch (InternalServerError e) {
            logger.info(TECH,"Internal Server Exception {}",e.getMessage());
            throw new InternalServerError(e.getMessage(), e.getRequestId());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            logger.info(TECH,"Null Pointer Exception {}",e.getMessage());
            throw new InternalServerError(internalServerExceptionMessage, requestId);
        } catch (BadRequestError e) {
            logger.info(TECH,"Bad Request Exception {}",e.getMessage());
            throw new BadRequestError(e.getMessage(), e.getrequestId());
        } catch (UnauthorizedError e) {
            logger.info(TECH,"Unauthorized Exception {}",e.getMessage());
            throw new UnauthorizedError(e.getMessage(), e.getRequestId());
        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info(TECH,"Exception {}",e.getMessage());
            throw new InternalServerError(internalServerExceptionMessage, requestId);
        }

    }
}


I am getting this highlighted error in an spring boot application. Have also tried after including the spring-data-elasticserach in the pom.xml file.

Can someone please suggest me the reason of why this error is occuring?

While deploying in the rancher cluster this error is occuring, in my local system the application is running fine.
```

Comment: Do not link images.  Cut and paste the error message into the question.

Comment: Can you please check now and suggest if any solution for the above mentioned problem please